# Automorphism group in finite dimensional case

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, $G_a := (K, +)$ be the additive group of $K$, and $X$ an affine variety.

I found the following claim: if $X$ admits a non-trivial $G_a$-action and $\dim(X) \ge 2$, then the group $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is infinite dimensional.

Reference: *The automorphism group of a rigid affine variety*, by I. Arzhantsev and S. Gaifullin.

Question: How do I see/prove this claim in a simple way?

Comment: I think this claim is false as stated. Take $K = \mathbb{F}_p$ to be the finite field on $p$ elements, and $X = \mathbb{A}^2_K$ to be the affine plane. Then $K$ acts nontrivially on $X$ by addition in each coordinate, but $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ can't be infinite-dimensional because there are only finitely many functions $X \to X$.

Comment: Looking at your reference, they start the introduction by saying that $K$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0, so the above can't occur.

Comment: @MartinSkilleter your counterexample is not correct, because an automorphism of the affine plane over $\mathbf{F}_p$ is not determined by its action on $\mathbf{F}_p^2$, and indeed automorphisms $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y+P(x))$, for $P$ ranging over polynomials in $\mathbf{F}_p[t]$, indicate that it's indeed infinite-dimensional. (Anyway the OP's definition of $\mathbf{G}_\mathrm{a}$ is not really correct either in such a case.)

Comment: Fix such a 1-parameter group of automorphisms $A$ acting as $(t,x)\mapsto u(t,x)$. If the algebra $R^A$ of $A$-invariant functions is infinite-dimensional (as vector space over the ground field), then for each $f\in R^A$ each $x\mapsto u(f(x),x)$ is an automorphism and should depend injectively on $f$. I don't know if $R^A$ is always infinite-dimensional for a $\mathbf{G}_\mathrm{a}$-action on an affine variety of dimension $\ge 2$.

Comment: @YCor you're completely right. I made the classic mistake of thinking polynomials over finite fields are determined by their values at points.

Comment: What does "infinite-dimensional" mean in this case? As far as I know, ${\rm Aut}(X)$ might not even be representable if $X$ is affine.